# Property 'xxx' not found on type org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hibernate learn hibernate is a hard work! this error show me hibernate:

```
        javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'usuarioPersonal' not found on type org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet
```

when across the view I trying to acces to property.

I have this relation: 1 proyect has N users (only 1 user can be responsable) and N Users 1 data information(name,lastname,email).

[image]

I´m use myeclipse and this generated my hbm and pojo, I´m review this information and to me it's ok.

Project DTO

```
    public class Proyecto implements java.io.Serializable {

// Fields

private Integer idproyecto;
private String nombre;
private Integer creadoPor;
private Timestamp inicia;
private Timestamp finaliza;
private Timestamp fecha;
private Integer estatus;
private Set tareas = new HashSet(0);
private Set usrProyectos = new HashSet(0);
```

UsrProyectoDTO

```
    public class UsrProyecto implements java.io.Serializable {

// Fields

private Integer idproyecto;
private UsuarioPersonal usuarioPersonal;
private Proyecto proyecto;
private Short estatus;
private Integer responsable;
```

UsuarioPersona DTO

```
    public class UsuarioPersonal implements java.io.Serializable {

// Fields

private Integer idusuarioPersonales;
private CtgPuesto ctgPuesto;
private String nombre;
private String paterno;
private String materno;
private Timestamp fecha;
private Set usrProyectos = new HashSet(0);
```

Proyecto.hbm.xml

```
<class name="com.bsd.projects.capadatos.dto.Proyecto" table="proyecto" catalog="bsd_proyectos">
    <id name="idproyecto" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="idproyecto" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="nombre" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="nombre" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="creadoPor" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="creado_por" />
    </property>
    <property name="inicia" type="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <column name="inicia" length="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="finaliza" type="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <column name="finaliza" length="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="fecha" type="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <column name="fecha" length="0" />
    </property>
    <set name="tareas" inverse="true">
        <key>
            <column name="proyecto_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.bsd.projects.capadatos.dto.Tarea" />
    </set>
    <set name="usrProyectos" inverse="true">
        <key>
            <column name="proyecto_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.bsd.projects.capadatos.dto.UsrProyecto" />
    </set>
    <property name="estatus" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="estatus" />
    </property>
</class>
```

UsrProyecto.hbm.xml

```
<class name="com.bsd.projects.capadatos.dto.UsrProyecto" table="usr_proyecto" catalog="bsd_proyectos">
    <id name="idproyecto" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="idproyecto" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="usuarioPersonal" class="com.bsd.projects.capadatos.dto.UsuarioPersonal" fetch="select">
        <column name="usaurio_personal_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="proyecto" class="com.bsd.projects.capadatos.dto.Proyecto" fetch="select">
        <column name="proyecto_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="estatus" type="java.lang.Short">
        <column name="estatus" />
    </property>
    <property name="responsable" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="responsable" />
    </property>
</class>
```

UsuarioPersonal.hbm.xml

```
<class name="com.bsd.projects.capadatos.dto.UsuarioPersonal" table="usuario_personal" catalog="bsd_proyectos">
    <id name="idusuarioPersonales" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="idusuario_personales" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="ctgPuesto" class="com.bsd.projects.capadatos.dto.CtgPuesto" fetch="select">
        <column name="ctg_puesto_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="nombre" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="nombre" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="paterno" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="paterno" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="materno" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="materno" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="fecha" type="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <column name="fecha" length="0" />
    </property>
    <set name="usrProyectos" inverse="true">
        <key>
            <column name="usaurio_personal_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.bsd.projects.capadatos.dto.UsrProyecto" />
    </set>
</class>
```

ProyectoDAO

```
public Proyecto findById(java.lang.Integer id) {
    log.debug("getting Proyecto instance with id: " + id);
    try {
        Proyecto instance = (Proyecto) getSession().get(
                "com.bsd.projects.capadatos.dto.Proyecto", id);
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

When I return my object to view

```
     request.setAttribute("detalleProyecto",proyecto);
```

and in detailproyect.jsp try access to "idusuarioPersonales"

```
<td>Id Personal:</td><td> <input type="text" value="${detalleProyecto.usrProyectos.usuarioPersonal.idusuarioPersonales}" />
```

Why can´t I´m access to this property? If the map associate 3 class

Comment: I´m reading in other post that the possible issues is not has getter and setter , but not is my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`usrProyectos` is a `Set`. You need to iterate over it in your JSP and then access its properties.

Comment: Thanks, but I return a object Proyecto, I can´t iterate

Comment: You should iterate over `detalleProyecto.usrProyectos`